# How to post DbGeography param to MVC?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, geospatial

I am trying to expose an API that will allow users to post polygons to persist on the server. I am using ASP.NET MVC 5. How do I format the AJAX parameters correctly to post the request for DbGeography? This is what I am trying:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/map',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        Title: 'My Title',
        MyGEOG: {
            WellKnownText: 'POLYGON ((30 10, 10 20, 20 40, 40 40, 30 10))'
        }
    }
});
```

This is how my MVC action signature looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("map")]
    public JsonResult Post(MyShape newShape) {...}
```

Also my `MyShape` class:

```
public class MapShape
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography MyGEOG { get; set; }
}
```

When putting a breakpoint in the action, `newShape.Title` does show as `My Title`, but `MyGEOG` is null when the AJAX post happens. What is the correct format of the parameter to post correctly as a `DbGeography` type?

Comment: To further clarify how you are intending to store the data on the API side, can you please include your newShape class definition please?

Comment: I needed geography for elevation.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the DBGeography object is immutable, meaning that you can't write to it once it has been created.  When you instantiate your MapShape class in the model binder, the MyGEO property is null.  In other words, you are trying to set a property on a null object.

The only way to "create" a DBGeography object is using one of the factory methods like:

**FromText** - Creates a new DbGeometry value based on the specified well known text value.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673669(v=vs.110).aspx

So, to pass in the **Title** and **WellKnownText** values to you controller, I suggest creating a Data Transfer Object (**DTO**) to act as proxy for the information.

```
public class MapShapeDTO
{
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string WellKnownText { get; set; }
}
```

Your Ajax gets simplified like this

```
$.ajax({
url: '/api/map',
type: 'POST',
data: {
    Title: 'My Title',
    WellKnownText: 'POLYGON ((30 10, 10 20, 20 40, 40 40, 30 10))'
    }
});
```

And your controller, you can use the DTO to create the MapShape object.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("map")]
public JsonResult Post(MapShapeDTO dto)
    {
        MapShape m = new MapShape()
            {
                Title = dto.Title,
                MyGEOG = System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.FromText(dto.WellKnownText)
            };
      ...
    }
```

Comment: This solution is only acceptable as a work around. Why isn't there a more elegant way (using ModelBinder or the like) to address this kind of problem? People are seeking for help for this problem all over the web.